# Angular ng-click with inline function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does `onclick="window.history.back()"` work and angular's `ng-click="window.history.back()"` doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

You can make this work adding `window` to your `$scope`, or even better to `$rootScope` so every `$scope` has access to `window` and thus your initial attemp would work as you've expected.

Example adding it to `$rootScope`:

```
<script>
  app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.window = window
  }])
</script>
```

Then you just call:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="window.history.back()">Go back</button>
```

or:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="window.alert('it works!')">Alert!</button>
```

or whatever variable or function in global javascript scope you want.

Answer (score 3):

**onclick** is an javascript event, so it can call function in javascript window object.

Where as

**ng-click** is an angular directive, which can only call functions which is available in the $scope. window is not available in $scope.

Answer (score 2):

because in the template you use the controller or directive scope.  So angular expects the scope object to have a property named window instead of searching for it in the global scope of the script

Answer (score 2):

`onclick="window.history.back()"` works because it is vanilla JavaScript and onclick is an event on the element.

`ng-click="window.history.back()"` doesn't work because ng-click is an angular directive and angular is looking for an object called window on the controller's scope.

You can gain access to the window object, in angular the suggested way is to declare a dependency on the $window service and do any operations required on the $window object.

Reasons to use $window service: it helps to do unit testing when using $window service and not the global window object.

EDIT: below info used from Pro AngularJS book - chapter 19

**Why and When to Use the Global Object Services**

The main reason that AngularJS includes these services is to make testing easier. I get into testing in Chapter 25, but
an important facet of unit testing is the need to isolate a small piece of code and test its behavior without testing the
components it depends on—in essence, creating a focused test. The DOM API exposes functionality through global
objects such as document and window. These objects make it hard to isolate code for unit testing without also testing
the way that the browser implements its global objects. Using services such as $document allows AngularJS code
to be written without directly using the DOM API global objects and allows the use of AngularJS testing services to
configure specific test scenarios.

Comment: How would it look like? after I inject the dependency... Do I have to create a local property on the scope? something like '$scope.window = ?'

Comment: yes, it would look like $scope.window = $window; but I don't recommend that, I suggest you write a function and call it in ng-click directive, it keeps your code clean, the angular team recommends to use the built-in services instead of using the global objects whenever possible, it maintains consistency with the rest of the AngularJS app.

Answer (score 1):

onclick is an js event, so it can call function in javascript window object.

But
ng-click is an angular directive, which can only call functions which is available in the $scope. window is not available in $scope. In angularjs we can do this by:

ng-click="doTheBack()"

$scope.doTheBack = function() {
`window.history.back();`
};